# Trying to determine proper notification design

Tags: wmi, listener, snmp, monitor, broadcast

We are building an internal application which will do the following:
  Run as a Windows Service
  Scan various server/platform types to confirm they are up and running
  Call the HeartBeat() method on all of our WCF services

What we want to do is then (for each server) send a notification broadcast so that a listener can pick up the data and display the realtime results in a dashboard environment.

In addition, the data will be collected by the listener for drilldown or reporting purposes.

I'm having a hard time determining what is the proper approach for broadcasting results.  SNMP seems like a good fit but I'm not sure how easy it would be to implement in C#.  I've looked at WMI and SNMP at the moment.

I'm looking for input on alternatives to either SNMP or WMI for the broadcast approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're programming exclusively in C#, then your best bet is to find some C# SNMP library that you will probably have to purchase.

If you're wanting to go with portability and standards, then go with SNMP.

If you're always going to be using Win32 C# then go with a WMI solution.

If you don't mind coding outside of C# and instead C or C++ and want to make things compatible with other systems, then I would highly recommend working with `Net-SNMP` and building an SNMP agent from that.